Local Maxima in a Dispersion Curve
Hello I programmed a dispersion curve and plotted the phase velocity.
I am noticing that for one of my modes (the S2 mode) my phase velocity reaches a maxima and then decreases. Is this a physical phenomena, or have I ran into a bug with my code? I am generating the dispersion curves using https://github.com/franciscorotea/Lamb-Wave-Dispersion.

Edit:
I am also noticing this occurs with the S3 mode as well, except now two local maxima exist. Usually when I look at these curves I notice only the behavior seen with the A1 & A2 modes, has anyone seen this behavior before?


So it turns out I found this issue, when using the built in plot function of Lamb-Wave-Dispersion it had a few datapoints there causing the entire plot to turn around. Extracting the data into excel and plotting showed the correct trends, without the crossover.
